# Deserialize json containing html without converting entities

Tags: java, json, jackson

it seems as though this should be simple to do, but I haven't managed to find the answer as yet.

I have some json similar to the following:

```
{
"standfirst":"\u2022 Alistair shreds field to win <strong>Olympic</strong> triathlon by 11 seconds"
}
```

Which I am deserializing using ObjectMapper in Jackson 1.9.8

When this is deserialized by jackson, the value of the standfirst property becomes

`"• Alistair shreds field to win <strong>Olympic</strong> triathlon by 11 seconds"`

whereas what I want it to be is:

"\u2022 Alistair shreds field to win Olympic triathlon by 11 seconds"

Any suggestions for how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson offers a way to specify custom escaping rules by registering custom `CharacterEscapes` object with `JsonFactory` (and each `ObjectMapper` has its own factory to configure). You can also directly specify `CharacterEscapes` for `JsonGenerator` if necessary.

Some examples of usage can be found from Jackson unit tests: for Jackson 1.9 classes are `org.codehaus.jackson.impl.TestCustomEscaping` and `org.codehaus.jackson.main.TestCharEscaping`.

Since this particular Unicode character is beyond ASCII range, you would define `getEscapeSequence(int ch)` to return proper escape sequence, and could otherwise use default settings.